# Instant plus with negative values

Tags: java, java-time, java.time.instant

I have this code

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
if (amountDays >= 0) {
    now = now.plus(amountDays, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
} else {
    now = now.minus(Math.abs(amountDays), ChronoUnit.DAYS);
}
```

And I was thinking to simplify it like this

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
now = now.plus(amountDays, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
```

However, I am unsure if `plus` works correctly with negative values or if that messes up the result.

Can I use `plus` like that, with possibly negative values?

Comment: In general you should of course prefer `minus` if you want to go back in time. Readability matters. In this particular case however, I would stick with just `plus` and maybe add a comment `// amountDays can also be negative` or just document it nicely in your javadoc. Voting to close this as it is opinion-based.

Comment: Note the javadoc of `plus` which says _"amountToAdd - the amount of the unit to add to the result, may be negative"_ - so it is supported and also expected that this method can be used like that.

Comment: @Zabuzard, I ask that because I am curious if something wrong can happen at execution, more than `opinion-based`.

Comment: Then the answer is **no**, it will work fine. The method, according to its javadoc, supports this use case.

Comment: [`minus` delegates to `plus`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/time/Instant.java#l982), so it shouldn't make much of a difference.

Comment: This is purely "style", no technical difference. Given the fact that "minus" just uses "plus", go for the 2nd, simple solution that requires way less code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### `plus` with negative values

The `plus` method supports adding negative times to go back in time, from its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#plus(long,java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)):

> amountToAdd - the amount of the unit to add to the result, **may be negative**

So all good, you can use it like that and it will work as expected.

---

### Implementation

Little trivia, the [current implementation](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/Instant.java#L980) of `minus` even delegates to `plus` with `-amountToSubtract` as value:

```
return (amountToSubtract == Long.MIN_VALUE
    ? plus(Long.MAX_VALUE, unit).plus(1, unit)
    : plus(-amountToSubtract, unit));
```

---

### Notes

In general, if you just want to go back in time, prefer using `minus` for readability.

In your particular case I would stick with just `plus` though to not bloat the code and logic unecessarily. Instead, prefer adding a comment

```
// amountDays may be negative
```

or ensure that your javadoc is clear about that.

Minor improvement, you can simplify your code from two statements to just one:

```
Instant now = Instant.now().plus(amountDays, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
```

Comment: Of course "now" is not a good name for the variable once you've offset the value by days, unless you've invented a time machine and go with it.

Answer (score 2):

Just take a look how `minus` is implemented

```
@Override
public Instant minus(long amountToSubtract, TemporalUnit unit) {
    return (amountToSubtract == Long.MIN_VALUE ? plus(Long.MAX_VALUE, unit).plus(1, unit) : plus(-amountToSubtract, unit));
}
```

Of course for readability sake it makes sense to use both `plus` and `minus` in proper situations but checking whether `amountDays` is greater or lower from `0` seems to be some kind of internal `Instant.plus` logic and is **deifinitely** not helping with readability of your code